# Selecting 10+ num_rows results from MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql

could someone tell me whats wrong on this mysql query?

```
$p = mysql_query("SELECT name,subname FROM brands GROUP BY name WHERE 
having count(*) > 10 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());
```

it says:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE having count(*) > 10 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1' at line 1

Comment: Technically, `GROUP BY` goes *after* a `where` clause. Remove the `WHERE`. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx

Comment: You should just delete WHERE, because you are using HAVING

Comment: Thank you Fred.. But, its not about GROUP BY(when delete group by command, nothing change).. and the WHERE clause is the main part of this query; i can not remove it.

Comment: haaa... sorry.... thank you so much :)

Comment: You're welcome @deniz .  I'll post an answer.

Comment: @deniz I've posted an answer below that you can mark as solved. *Cheers*

Answer (score 2):

`HAVING` does not use a `WHERE` clause, remove it.

```
$p = mysql_query("SELECT name,subname FROM brands GROUP BY name  
having count(*) > 10 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());
```

Consult:

- http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html

You should consider switching to [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) or [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `WHERE` clause, you already have a `HAVING` clause.

So, your statement must be :

```
$p = mysql_query("SELECT name,subname FROM brands GROUP BY name HAVING count(*) > 10 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());
```